# When I die minecraft unloads all the chunks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, linux, hosting

I have a minecraft server running on a dedicated server and when I log in everything is normal, but when I die, the world unloads around me... Everything I can see just unloads. I can't think of a valid reason but it acts as if my player does not exists and just unloads the world.

**Quick update:** It does not seem to be the BungeeCord proxy, we did a direct connection to the server instead of going through the proxy and it still happens, we think it may be a packet loss issue? or the server somehow forgets you are a player? No idea really.

I have tried many options, I am not sure if it is one of the my Java flags, but here is the details:

**Dedicated server:**
32GB RAM,
Intel Xeon (3.4GHz),
2TB HDD,
OS: Ubuntu Server 14.04

**Minecraft Client:** Happens to all

**Minecraft Server:**
Given 256MB (Xms) upto 4GB (Xmx),
Run with nice level of -15,
KCaulron-1.7.10-1492.155,
BungeeCord (KCauldron Fix),

**Start file / Java Flags:**
`nice -n -15 /usr/bin/java -Xmx4096M -Xms256M -server -Xrs -d64 -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90 -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=15 -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseBiasedLocking -XX:UseSSE=3 -XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:+ReduceSignalUsage -XX:+UseInterpreter -XX:+UseFastEmptyMethods -XX:+UseSharedSpaces -XX:AllocatePrefetchStyle=1 -XX:+AlwaysCompileLoopMethods -XX:SharedReadOnlySize=30m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+RewriteFrequentPairs -XX:+OptimizeStringConcat -XX:+CMSCleanOnEnter -XX:+UseSplitVerifier -XX:+UseInlineCaches -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui`

Any ideas would be amazing please, because I have no idea currently, I have used this world before and it has worked fine, the same server completely, only since we moved to this new server (I used to use a paid host, I now use my dedicated server) have we had this problem.

Please note I have looked at other problems on this forums and others, and to no avail, nothing helped. I did try them.

[image: picture of problem as seen in game]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what it looks like when you die?

Comment: @JohntheGreen Added a screenshot to main post, thanks for the reply, please note the world slowly just becomes nothing and all I see is the blank area

Comment: On this, we removed all plugins and all java flags and still the same...

Answer (score -3):

If you die in Minecraft, your stuff will despawn **after approximately 5 minutes.** *(or 6000 ticks.)*

Maybe try playing Minecraft on the newest versions:
***1.9 - 1.10 - 1.11 - 1.12 - 1.13***. If **none** of these new versions fix your problem, please reply, but I have never personally had any issues with these versions.

I also have some questions for you, like *are cheats enabled? is this a survival world only? or survival and creative?*

If this helps, you can press <kbd>F3</kbd> and then <kbd>A</kbd> to reload chunks.